# border-radius fails under safari (ugly clipping)

Tags: html, safari, css

Does anybody know a workaround for folowing 'bug' in Safari?

When I use `border-radius` to create rounded borders in CSS3 it just works fine on Safari, FF and so on.

But when the border-color is the color like in the background you can see the containers background overlapping the border.

You can try it here: http://de.roundedcorner.org/css3-rounded-corner-generator Just set the border-color and sites background to `#333333`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's most likely due to background clipping.

The following *should* correct that.

```
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
```

For some more on background-clip, have a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip

Comment: As a further note I would like to add that using this clipping option can cause a similar issue to occur inside the element, between the border and the background. Fun! :)

Comment: I'm having a rounded corner clipping problem too - I'm not sure if it falls under same remit, but the background clipping is not fixing it. It relates to a 'halo' of colour: http://jsfiddle.net/jSRND/

Any ideas? If it is not the same issue, will start a new thread.

Comment: Found a fix for this too, courtesy of @neil_pie on Twitter: http://jsfiddle.net/dwYCg/8/

Answer (score 2):

The background-clip property is used to determine whether the backgrounds extends into the border or not. The default is border-box, which means it DOES extend into it, but if you set it to padding-box, it doesn’t. if you use content-box the background only extends to the content area. (source: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/)

Solution for your problem is to use: 
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;

It’s important to note that if you are using the shorthand notation to specify your other background properties then this should be added after those. It seems that the shorthand notation implies a default clip value which will override one that’s previously set. (source: http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed)