# Rounded corners overlapping

Tags: html, css, safari

On safari 6 or earlier - the image overlaps the rounded border. Is there an easy fix to this? I tried adding a surrounding div with overflow:hidden but the result was the same.

The image size is not known before hand either.

http://jsfiddle.net/89VvB/

```
img {
    border:5px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps by putting the `img` a `div` and doing the rounding on the latter?

Comment: -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;

does this help? Can't test it as I don't have an old version

Comment: @Pekka - Nope, already tried this. Needed to float it though and add overflow:hidden since I don't know the size of the image before hand.

Comment: @Simon R - Well, the only thing yours adds is moz-border-radius - and this is a bug in safari - so no, it doesn't help but thanks for looking!

Comment: This still occurs in Safari 6 on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If the image size is not going to change, you can use a `<div>` and set the image to be the background.

See http://jsfiddle.net/89VvB/5/

Note that I had to specify the height and width of the `<div>` so the image would appear.

You may also want to see this: [border-radius fails under safari (ugly clipping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210161/border-radius-fails-under-safari-ugly-clipping)

Comment: Unfortunately the size can change and is not known - (facebook api results).

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, this is a known bug in older versions of safari. (In fact it occurs in other old browsers as well, but the affected versions have moslty fallen out of use)

The browser draws the foreground image in front of the border. There's no way around this.

The only solutions are:

- To switch from using a foreground image to a background image. This works, but is a pain from a semantic angle, and can cause it's own problems.
- Put the `img` tag inside a `div`, and put the border onto the `div` instead of directly onto the `img`. This does involve extra markup, but is probably the most reliable way of fixing it. Note that you'll probably need to set the `div` to `display:inline-block` so it shrinks to fit the size of the image.
- Or of course, you could just edit your image manually; give it rounded corners and a border using Photoshop (or Gimp, or whatever other tool you use), and you won't need the CSS at all. Its a bit of an old-school solution, but it is fairly certain to work.

Comment: I tried your second solution, but even that doesn't seem to work. I get the exact same result. I'm not sure why that is, as I have set overflow to hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/89VvB/12/

Comment: Hmm, oh well. The second solution did used to work with some of the other browsers that had similar bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ditching the border and using -webkit-box-shadow instead is the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QyY3/40/

```
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px black;
```

Of course, I only do this in browsers like safari 6 or earlier.